# Finding files in a specific directory path

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to set up a cron job to delete old files generated in certain path on a server.

My issue is that I *only* want to clean up the old files in a named `cleanupdir` which is duplicated across many parent directories.

Writing out all of these is very time consuming:

```
find ~/dir\ 1/cleanupdir/ -name *.htm -mtime +7 -delete
find ~/dir\ 2/cleanupdir/ -name *.htm -mtime +7 -delete
find ~/dir\ 3/cleanupdir/ -name *.htm -mtime +7 -delete
...
```

Running this deletes many files I want to keep

```
find ~/ -name *.htm -mtime +7 -delete
```

Ideally I'd want something like a wildcard for the path so I could run

```
find ~/*/cleanupdir/ -name *.htm -mtime +7 -delete
```

but that seems to not be supported

My other attempt was to do something like

```
find ~/ *.htm -mtime +7 | grep /cleanupdir/ | xargs rm
```

However the spaces in the `dir 1` etc directories mean this won't work.

Either using a bash script, or clever single line using find works for me, as I said it's specifically for a cronjob.

Comment: Please give some more information, not only on the files you want to delete, but also the ones you want to keep.

Comment: `find ~/*/cleanupdir` may work better if you write it with a full path `find /home/user/*/cleanupdir`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your last attempt looks fine, except you need to quote the wildcard so the shell doesn't expand it to a list of `*.htm` files in the current directory.

```
find ~/*/cleanupdir/ -name '*.htm' -mtime +7 -delete
```

Answer (score -1):

How about something like `find ~ -name "*.htm" -wholename "*/cleanupdir/*" -mtime +7 -delete` ?